# Pig - Convert rows into multiple columns

Tags: apache-pig

Can we convert input rows to multiple columns terminated by Three.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one naive solution.

Grouping every three rows using `RANK` and `GROUP`, and `FILTER` by each of three conditions.

#### My Pig Script

```
A = Load '/path_to_data/data' as (c1 : chararray);
B = RANK A;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE (rank_A+2)/3 as id, c1;

D = FOREACH (GROUP C BY id) {
        ONE = FILTER C BY c1 matches 'One:.*';

        TWO = FILTER C BY c1 matches 'Two:.*';

        THREE = FILTER C BY c1 matches 'Three:.*';

        GENERATE 
            group as id
            , FLATTEN(ONE.c1) as c1_one
            , FLATTEN(TWO.c1) as c1_two
            , FLATTEN(THREE.c1) as c1_three
        ;
    };

DUMP D;
```

#### My Result

```
(1,One:"A",Two:"2",Three:"last")
(2,One:"B",Two:"1",Three:"first")
```